# Method to find if the string has words in the given set of keywords

Tags: r

I have a Dataset with ticket details including Short_Description and Notes column and I have one more Dataset with keywords and corresponding Categories. I have to run the Short_Description and Notes through keywords and find if we have the keywords available and select the corresponding category.

The problem is the data is huge(more than 1500 rows) and the keywords is around 600 rows of different categories and 5 columns with the keywords. 
It take huge time(more than 5hrs) to run the code as i am using FOR loop.

Is there any way or any other function i can use to optimize the code?

I am using str_detect() where I get 600 rows of output for single ticket and

```
Data= read.csv("Open_tickets.csv")
  k= read_excel("Keywords_All.xlsx")
  setDT(k)[, Seq := rowid(Assignment.Group)]
  k[,4:13]=tolower(unlist(k[,4:13]))
  k[,4:13]=str_replace_all(unlist(k[,4:13]),"[^a-zA-Z\\s]","")

  sd= data.frame()
  notes=data.frame()
  for (i in 1:NROW(Data1))   
  {
    for (j in 1:NROW(k))
    {  
        Data$Short_Description[i]=tolower(Data$Short_Description[i])
        str1=str_replace_all(Data$Short_Description[i],"[^a-zA-Z\\s]","")
        newd1 = str_detect(str1,unlist(k[j,4:8]))
        newd1=as.data.frame(t(newd1))
        newd1$Assignment_Group= Data$Assignment_Group[i]
        newd1$inc= Data1$Number[i]
        newd1$Short_Description = Data$Short_Description[i]
        newd1$Notes=Data$Notes[i]
        newd1$Subcategory=k$`Sub Category`[j]
        newd1$Category=k$Category[j]
        newd1$seq = k$Seq[j]
        sd=rbind(sd,newd1)

        Data$Notes[i]=tolower(Data$Notes[i])
        str2= str_replace_all(Data$Notes[i],"[^a-zA-Z\\s]","")
        newd2 = str_detect(str2,unlist(k[j,4:8]))
        newd2=as.data.frame(t(newd2))
        newd2$Assignment_Group= Data1$Assignment_Group[i]
        newd2$inc= Data1$Number[i]
        newd2$Short_Description = Data1$Short_Description[i]
        newd2$Notes=Data1$Notes[i]
        newd2$Subcategory=k$`Sub Category`[j]
        newd2$Category=k$Category[j]
        newd2$seq = k$Seq[j]
        notes=rbind(notes,newd2)
       }
      }
```

I get the output dataframes with True and False values with corresponding keywords.

Answer (score 0):

For this, you can use Aho-Corasick algorithm, it is a text searching algorithm with complexity O(n), you can find a package implementing it in R language here,

for bioc:
https://rdrr.io/bioc/Starr/man/match_ac.html

for CRAN:
https://rdrr.io/cran/AhoCorasickTrie/.

Comment: Thank you for the info. But when I am using the match_ac() the R session is getting terminated. can you guide me with what should i keep the nseq as?